Spring security configurations return 401 unauthorized for POST request
I am trying to post method in spring security but I get "401Unauthorized" in postman.
And intellij said "Role not found" but database has "ADMIN" and "USER" roles.
My endpoint is "/auth/register"
 @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody RegisterDto registerDto) {
        if (userRespository.existsByUsername(registerDto.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Username is taken");
        }
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
        user.setUsername(registerDto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registerDto.getPassword()));

        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("ADMIN").orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Role not found"));
        user.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(role));  
        userRespository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User registered successfully");
    }

this is my security configuration code :
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}

here is my entities :
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Role> roles=new ArrayList<>();

public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

here is required dependencies :
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


I have extended from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and I have this method:    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/auth/**");
}

You can enable the logs and see where and why you get an HTTP 401 by setting in your property file: logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-enable-logging.
